# Bluetooth driver accessing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I recently found out that I couldn't use my Bluetooth anymore cause it wasn't even accessible from my device ( by accessible I mean not being able to be turned on and off). I then followed the instructions for a device with an Windows 10 OS. They advised me to uninstall the driver ( which was hidden under device manager but fully up to date) and so did I but when I restarted my laptop the computer couldn't recognise the Intel drivers.
I then downloaded them from Intel support page but to no avail because no "Bluetooth" type appeared under the Device Manager list as it once did. How can I properly install the drivers and have functioning Bluetooth connection in my device ?

Comment: Run your computer hardware diagnostic app. See if the bluetooth hardware is OK.

Comment: As suggested above. There is a strong possibility of it being broken now.